# When adding margin to images with grid area , the images collapse?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i really try and try to make margin for grid area elements ( 4 pic )
i want to make margin right and margin left with maintaining of centering of elements

i want the 4 pic still in center with left margin and right margin !

code of html

```
    <div class="image">
        <img class="one" src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="two" src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="three" src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="four"  src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

code of CSS

```css
.image {
      min-width: 100%;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: 
      "o th"
      "t f"
      ;

  }

  .image .one {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
      grid-area: o;

      
  }

  .image .two {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: t;
}
  
.image .three {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: th;
}

.image .four {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'column-gap' property for Grid boxes:

```
.image {
  height:500px;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "o th"
  "t f";
   column-gap: 4px;
}
```

You can use the 'row-gap' property to leave space at the top and bottom.

Take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7c4u0eva/).

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: sir chong , i want to make the four images in center with left and right margin

Comment: You mean you want to add {margin: auto;} to .image?

Comment: Sir Chong , when adding a left and right margin ; the centering is collapse with collapsing effect on the images